# Extract data from ows_MetaInfo

Tags: caml, ssom

I'm trying to extract all data from an SPListItem. Most of the data is in the ows_MetaInfo attribute in some strange format. Is there a way to either deserialize ows_MetaInfo, or get the fields in an expanded form?

I found following resources:

- http://labs.steveottenad.com/getting-ows_metainfo-with-spservices/
- https://www.concurrency.com/blog/w/sharepoint-lists-web-service-and-metainfo-field

suggesting to use `<ViewFields Properties='True' />`, but this doesn't work:

```
var list = web.Lists[id];
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.ViewAttributes = "Properties=\"True\"";
foreach (SPListItem item in list.GetItems(query))
{
    var xml = item.Xml;
    ...
}
```

Comment: your second link is broken and the first one is for JavaScript which would explain why it doesnt work.

Comment: Fixed the second link, thank you. I know it's javascript, but it's all I found and I hoped the CAML there could be used the same way with server side. Any helpful ideas?

Comment: you can call the field names i think by using item["internalname"], though I could be wrong